# Search Form in Zend layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I need to use a form in the layout as it will appear on all my pages ( a search form)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ControllerPlugin for this Task.

```
// application/plugins/Search.php

class My_Plugin_Search extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    /**
     * PreDispatch
     * 
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request 
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $form = new My_Form_Search();
        $view->searchForm = $form;
    }
}
```

and in your layout.phtml

```
echo $this->searchForm;
```

To use the Plugin, you have to register it, in your application.ini:

> resources.frontController.plugins.0 = "My_Plugin_Search"

Answer (score 1):

this works just fine:

```
<div id="searchForm">
     <h2>Search Site</h2>
     <?php
     $searchForm = new Application_Form_Search();
     $searchForm->setAction('/search');
     echo $searchForm;
     ?>
</div>
```

this has the advantage of being simple, it by no means the only way to accomplish this task.